# Bitmap holding integer values

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have 4 bitmaps that I want to store values for each uniquely. The values would be coming from an external source and i want to map these values to each bitmap specifically. So bitmap1 should be associated with 1, bitmap2 with 2 etc. So if i should click on any of these bitmaps a toast message would pop up with the number associated to that bitmap. Currently i have the bitmaps stored in an array then pulled and displayed on a surfaceview. I want to know the best way or if there is someway to associate the bitmaps to integer values uniquely, even after removing 2 or 3 of the bitmaps the remaining bitmaps still hold there integer values. Any tips or suggestions on this process ? thank you

Comment: what u have tried yet...and if possible share your code

Comment: initially i tried a list with the values, and the key value for the bitmap array which i use like a key, but the problem is the bitmap list decreases when a bitmap element is removed from the bitmap list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your bitmap in a `HashMap<Integer,Bitmap>`

this way you can identify your Bitmaps uniquely and maintain the hierarchy and positions.

Comment: And [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for an ordered map…

Comment: Thanks for your tip, and yes i have my bitmaps in a map now but i was wondering if each bitmap could keep a value. After clicking on a bitmap i have it removed from the map and so doing the values array i had set up is rearranged. Now i tried storing the values in an array but when the bitmaps get taken out the values array decreases by the same amount

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try HashMap < Bitmap, Integer > for the mapping. Yes, a bitmap as a key. I haven't tried running it myself, but Java doesn't complain on such a declaration => formally, Bitmap qualifies as a key.
2. If #1 works, you're done. Just remember to remove your bitmap from the HashMap. Otherwise, create a wrapper class for Bitmap that has the features required to serve as a HashMap key, and use that class in your collections.

Edit: updated formatting so that SO displays it right.

Comment: will give this a try as well thanks for your input, but you understand what i am trying to accomplish right? Is this a good way to go about this mini game?

Comment: I think I do. This approach seems to be valid: I have used it in similar situations. HashMap just wants the right equals and hash code methods, which is not a big deal in both cases.

Comment: ... oh, just for clarity. This map is in addition to what you use now rather than instead of that.

Comment: of course, it is like selecting the bitmap with the correct answer under neath it basically. The problem i was having before is after removing a bitmap or 2 from the bitmap hashmap the answers list size decreases as i have them in the same for loop, using i as the index to test the values on